# How to disable anchor tag click when clicked on bootstrap toggle button inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, togglebutton

I am new to BootstrapToggle and I am using Bootstrap toggle button inside an anchor tag like this :

[image]

Here is the code snippet :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="alert('hello'); return false;">
   <span>Hello World</span>
   
   <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Accepted" data-off="Rejected" data-onstyle="success">
        
</a>
```

Now If I toggle the button the anchor tag alert also gets called. I want only my 
button to be toggled If I change it not the anchor tag alert should be called in that case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remove `onclick="alert();"` and put `href="javascript:void(0);`

Comment: But what If I also want to call javascript method on anchor click as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a strange solution to wrap the button with the anchor, but if this is what you want...

You can try something like that

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span id="MySpan">Hello World</span>
   
   <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Accepted" data-off="Rejected" data-onstyle="success">
        
</a>

<script>

$('#MySpan').click(function() {

alert('hello world');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Kordi but What I really want is the onclick method on anchor tag not on toggle button and when we click on the toggle button that anchor click must not be invoked

Comment: @Lakhtey, I think you are contradicting yourself. You are saying that you don't want the anchor click to be invoked, and this is the solution that kavish and Mayank suggested. But then you said that you want the javascript to be called. A bit confusing to be honest.

Comment: basically What I want is a onclick on my anchor tag but dont want to trigger that onclick when button gets toggled. OnClick should be called only when the span text inside anchor tag is clicked. Hope now you get my point

Comment: Why do you want to wrap the toggle button with the anchor?

Comment: Thats a template I am following

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
<a onclick="alert('hello'); return false;">
```

use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span>Hello World</span>
   
   <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Accepted" data-off="Rejected" data-onstyle="success">
        
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank but what If I also want to call a method on anchor click as well.

Comment: Then use `onclick`, the above solution is for dealing with `href`

Comment: but in that case onclick triggers also if I toggle the button.

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: The issue is that I dont want onclick to trigger if I toggle the button and dont want button to toggle if I click on the anchor link

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use as i had encounter the same problem.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
```

Comment: Thanks Kavish but What I I also want to call a javascript method on anchor click as well